# issue with single sign on Azure active directory javascript library

Tags: dynamics-crm, adal, adal.js

We have single sign on enabled for our MS Dynamics 365 CRM instance to make a calls to an API hosted in Azure. On launch of CRM we have the following JavaScript that executes. This works most of the time, but on occasion we get "Invalid argument" popup. I am relatively new to using Adal.js and have no idea what is causing this. Any trouble shooting tips appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
config = {
    ApiUrl: configData["ApiUrl"],
    SubscriptionKey: configData["SubscriptionKey"],
    trace: configData["trace"],
    AcceptHeader: configData["AcceptHeader"],
    ContentTypeHeader: configData["ContentTypeHeader"],
    tenant: configData["tenant"],
    clientId: configData["clientId"],
    tokenStoreUrl: configData["tokenStoreUrl"],
    cacheLocation: configData["cacheLocation"],
    GraphApi: configData["GraphApi"]
};
// Check For & Handle Redirect From AAD After Login
authContext = new window.AuthenticationContext(config);
var isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);

if (isCallback) {
    authContext.handleWindowCallback();
}

var loginError = authContext.getLoginError();
if (loginError) {
    console.log('ERROR:\n\n' + loginError);
}
authContext.popUp = true;
if (isCallback && !loginError) {
    window.location = authContext._getItem(authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST);
}
var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
if (!user) {                            
    authContext.clearCache(); 
    sessionStorage["adal.login.request"] = "";                           
    authContext.login();
}

window.parent.authContext = authContext;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? Would you be able to post your solution?

Comment: Yes, see the answer I posted below. I forgot I actually had asked a question, otherwise I would have replied sooner while the resolution was still fresh in my mind. Hope the answer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while since I last looked at this, however I managed to get it resolved at the time. I implemented a locking mechanism, to ensure the login completes before trying to obtain a token.

Here is the updated code:

```
config = {
                            ApiUrl: configData["ApiUrl"],
                            SubscriptionKey: configData["SubscriptionKey"],
                            trace: configData["trace"],
                            AcceptHeader: configData["AcceptHeader"],
                            ContentTypeHeader: configData["ContentTypeHeader"],
                            tenant: configData["tenant"],
                            clientId: configData["clientId"],
                            tokenStoreUrl: configData["tokenStoreUrl"],
                            cacheLocation: configData["cacheLocation"],
                            GraphApi: configData["GraphApi"],
                            loadFrameTimeout: 10000
                        };


                    // Check For & Handle Redirect From AAD After Login
                    authContext = new window.AuthenticationContext(config);
                    var isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);

                    if (isCallback) {
                        authContext.handleWindowCallback();
                    }

                    var loginError = authContext.getLoginError();
                    if (loginError) {
                        // TODO: Handle errors signing in and getting tokens
                        console.log('ERROR:\n\n' + loginError);
                    }
                    authContext.popUp = true;
                    if (isCallback && !loginError) {
                        window.location = authContext._getItem(authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST);
                    }
                    var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
                    if (!user) {
                        authContext.clearCache();
                        sessionStorage["adal.login.request"] = "";
                        authContext.callback = function (error, token, msg) {
                            // remove lock
                            window.top.loginLock = null;
                            if (!!token) {
                                getGraphApiTokenAndUpdateUser(authContext);
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log('ERROR:\n\n' + error);
                            }
                        };

                        if (typeof (window.top.loginLock) == "undefined" || window.top.loginLock  == null) {
                            // Create lock
                            window.top.loginLock  = true;
                            authContext.login();
                        }
                    }

                    window.parent.authContext = authContext;
```